# How to individually set mbstring.func_overload = 0 for Roundcube

Tags: php, email, vps, setting, roundcube

I got VPS Debian 7 Apache + PHP.
In php.ini I set mbstring.func_overload = 2 for all services.
But unfortunately Roundcube doesn't work with this setting: ERROR: Wrong 'mbstring.func_overload' option value. Read REQUIREMENTS section in INSTALL file or use Roundcube Installer, please!
How to set individually mbstring.func_overload = 0 for Roundcube? Or how can I set mbstring.func_overload for each sites individually?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote in this file (Debian 7) /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory "/var/lib/roundcube/">
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```